# Cosa significa "firulí firulà" in questo testo?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *E il tuo dimon son io* di Michele Mari, tratto dal libro *Tu, sanguinosa infanzia*, ho letto:

> «Non era piú niente, una spoglia secca, una *forma*, capisci, nient'altro che un involucro vuoto in cui, giorno dopo giorno per anni, tu hai continuato a versare inutile odio. Gli attribuivi oceani di soddisfazione e un costante, interiore **firulí firulà** ma soffrivi per niente, perché Baldini era giú con me nell'abiso gelato ed io me lo tenevo ben stretto, e vuoi sapere una cosa che ti farà piacere? *urlava*, non ha smesso di urlare nemmeno adesso».

Questa espressione, "firulí firulà" è nuova per me. Non l'ho trovata in nessun dizionario, ma una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che appare nel testo di alcune canzoni. Me ne potreste spiegare il senso nel brano precedente?

Comment: Direi che è onomatopeico per “fischettare allegramente”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come già detto in un commento, “firulì firulà” in genere evoca un fischiettare allegro e spensierato, o il suono di strumenti a fiato di registro acuto.

In questo contesto, insieme agli “oceani di soddisfazione”, descrive l'apparente serenità interiore di Baldini (smentita a quel che pare dal personaggio che sta parlando).

Lo possono confermare, più o meno direttamente, altri brani letterari:

> ...subito dopo posava il tovagliolo sul tavolo per coprire le briciole che aveva fatto, fischiettando firulì firulà.
>   (Gaia Rayneri, [*Pulce non c'è*](https://books.google.it/books?id=J2tb_Up7-acC&pg=PA6&dq=%22firul%C3%AC%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6gsi4n7zXAhVFuBoKHROfAQU4HhDoAQhVMAY#v=onepage&q=%22firul%C3%AC%22&f=false))
>
> Poi io le alzavo un braccio secco e facevo finta che era un piffero e dicevo firulì firulà e lei faceva il pianoforte sulla mia gamba.
>   (Viola Ardone, [*La ricetta del cuore in subbuglio*](https://books.google.it/books?id=AIlkAXFwLWYC&pg=PT13&dq=%22firul%C3%AC%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx6rrwn7zXAhWE1RoKHQuaD2E4PBDoAQhEMAU#v=onepage&q=%22firul%C3%AC%22&f=false))
>
> e questo, questo soprattutto – come ci ricorda il suono, firulì firulà, delle zampogne –, è ciò che conta.
>   (Italo Calvino, [*Marcovaldo*](https://books.google.it/books?id=hfSGNauo-A4C&pg=PT135&dq=%22firul%C3%AC%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijusyin7zXAhUFnRoKHTniA2kQ6AEITjAF#v=onepage&q=%22firul%C3%AC%22&f=false))